# What is the solution of the inequality $-3 < 2x+1 < 5$

Tags: inequality

I am very poor in the mathematics and its been decade for me, when I did that in my schooling. Can anyone give solution step by step and possible question of inequality with different patterns? What is the category/type of this equation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Proper formatting is expected; for some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtracting $1$ from each side gives
$$-4<2x<4$$
Dividing by $2$ from each side gives
$$-2<x<2$$
which is equal to $$|x|<2$$

Comment: Nice speed! (+1)

Comment: +1 , Thank you . it would be very nice if i can accommodate this logic in any formula? is there any?

Comment: @Viraj_T...There is no formula..You can solve them separately or even as a whole.. if you want to learn more...Google compound inequalities...

Answer (score 0):

In this type of questions you have to find value of variable in this case variable is $x$ using mathematical operations.

In this case to find value of $x$

Step 1 -

Subtract 1.

Step 2 -

Divide by 2.